# I cannot multiply by a float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm a beginner in python, and I'm trying to solve a problem to practice my knowledge to get further. I'm facing a problem. In `nextday = nextday *(10/100)`

The problem that I'm trying to solve is:

"As a future athlete you just started your practice for an upcoming event. Given that on the first day you run x miles, and by the event you must be able to run y miles, calculate the number of days required for you to finally reach the required distance for the event, if you increase your distance each day by 10% from the previous day. Print one integer representing the number of days to reach the required distance."

I've tried to set `nextday = nextday * 0.10` but it doesn't run. I'm not receiving an error when I'm doing that, but when I submit the two inputs that I have and then nothing happen. The **plus sign** works but not multiplication.

```
firstday = float(input("How many miles you will run the first day? "))
event = float(input("How many miles is the event? "))
nextday = firstday
days = 0
while firstday <= event:
    nextday = nextday * (10/100)
    firstday = nextday
    days = days + 1

print(days)
```

Comment: Next day -> 0 when you multiply it multiple times. To oncrease by 10% multiply it with 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

You're taken into what is called infinite loop where end condition of the while loop is never met.

```py
firstday = float(input("How many miles you will run the first day? "))
event = float(input("How many miles is the event? "))
nextday = firstday
days = 0
while firstday <= event:
    nextday = nextday * (10/100) # next day becomes 1/10 of next day so it never increases
    firstday = nextday
    days = days + 1

print(days)
```

Correct code in increasing would be:

```py
firstday = float(input("How many miles you will run the first day? "))
event = float(input("How many miles is the event? "))
nextday = firstday
days = 0
while firstday <= event:
    nextday = nextday * 1.1 # 10% increace! not tenth of previous value
    firstday = nextday
    days = days + 1

print(days)
```

Comment: I think this is still wrong, You forgot to change the Stopping criterion of the `while` loop to `day<=event`

Comment: I do not believe so. As we are calculating when 10% increase by day exceeds the event length. (which could be reduced to simple logarithmic function)